# Export one dataset each replication from a Parameter Variations experiment

Tags: anylogic

In a parameter variation experiment I am plotting data from a dataset located in Main. Like this:
[image]

I use the following code to display data in the plot:

```
if(root.p_X == 7) {
plot.addDataSet(root.ds_waitTime,
    "X = " + root.p_X,
    transparent(red, 0.5), true, Chart.INTERPOLATION_LINEAR,
1, Chart.POINT_NONE);
else if(root.p_X == 14) {
plot.addDataSet(root.ds_waitTime,
    "X = " + root.p_X,
    transparent(red, 0.5), true, Chart.INTERPOLATION_LINEAR,
1, Chart.POINT_NONE);
```

My question is related to exporting the underlying data. I am not sure what the best way is to export the data. For each simulation run, I want to export dataset `root.ds_waitTime` to a csv or excel file, annotated with the value of `root.p_X == 14`. I know you can add datasets to a 2d histogram dataset, but this also transforms the data, so that doesn't seem a good option. Also, I do not have set up an external database, and I'd prefer not to.

Is it possible to save `root.ds_waitTime` to column 1 and 2 for simulation run 1, to column 3 and 4 for simulation run 2, and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Experiment window do the following:

1. Add a variable called i and assign 0 as its initial value
2. Add an Excel File element and link it to the file you want on your PC in its properties. Name the block "excelFile" which is the default name.

Then, in the Experiment window properties under "Java Actions" in the field "After Simulation Run", use the following code (where dataSet is the name of your dataset):

```
excelFile.writeDataSet(dataSet, 1, 2, 1 + i*2);
i++;
```

This way, after each simulation run, the dataset is written to the next 2 rows.

The syntax I used refers to the:

- Sheet Number i.e. 1
- Row Number i.e. 2; I use 2 to leave space for a top row in which you can add in your headers outside AnyLogic, to the file directly
- Column Number i.e. 1 + i*2

For the header row, you can alternatively add the following code:

```
excelFile.setCellValue(dataset name, 1, 1, 1 + i*2);
```

Comment: Thank you, Emile. That is exactly what I wanted, and it is quite simple. Is there a way to add the name and value of the parameter that I am varying in the experiment to the Excel header row?

Comment: I'm glad this helps. To do what you are asking, you need to follow the same logic using 
excelFile.setCellValue("parameter", 1, 1, 1 + i*2);
Using "setCellValue" instead of "writeDataSet" allows you to fill just one single cell. You'll just have to play with the row and column numbers to match what you're trying to do.